# Trying to use a png image for my html code but not working, displays x mark rather than image

Tags: jquery, html, image, tags, png

So I have been working on a simple code for html img tags, where I am trying to grab a image and make it into a link so when image is clicked the link will open up, but the link Must open up on spate tab. For right now just grabbing the image into the website is Not working.

my Code for far.....

```
<html>
<body>
<img src = "CardTapp.png" height="42" width="42"/>
</body>
</html>
```

but this code is not doing the trick

Comment: Is there a file called `CardTapp.png`? Is it located in the same folder as your HTML file? Do you get any errors in your browser console (404 error or otherwise)? Can you create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: The `[x]` means the image is either not found or is not an image.  Press F12 on your browser and look on the network tab (then reload if you're unfortunate enough to have to use IE).   Try loading the image directly, eg:  `http://yoursite/cardtapp.png`

Comment: @showdev so basically I have the image on my desktop, that's why I didn't set any path way

Comment: @freedomn-m I should try uploading the image directly? meaning put my website url then image tag?

Comment: You may want to review [Dealing With Files @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files).

Comment: <img src = " https://admin.elliemae.com/encompassconsumerconnect/cms/index.html#/site-builder/3869665153?token=NRJVQk2veAPwnmX9B1q2onvzzEmi/CardTapp.png" height="42" width="42"/>

Comment: that's not working ...

Comment: Well, we don't know the url to your site or where your file is located within your site, so can't tell you what url to use.  But *start* by pointing the browser to the image, not using an `<img>` tag.  eg, in your browser, enter `http://admin.elliema.com/ecompassconsumerconnect/cmd/cardtapp.png` - of course this depends on where your image is located and only you know that so you will get a 404 if you don't put the correct path in or your image doesn't exist.

Comment: so don't user img tags for the path? @freedomn-m

Comment: <html><body><img src= "C:\Users\ahaque\Desktop\CardTapp.jpg.jpg"></body></html>

Comment: this part I just posted is not working

Comment: anything wrong I'm doing?

Comment: For a start, you have ".jpg.jpg" - but I don't think you have the concept of not using html to load your image into the browser to determine it's location by putting the path into the browser address bar before adding it to an image tag.

Comment: okay what I'm asking is this code enough to get the image to view?? (of course if the path is correct) - <img src ="C:\Users\ahaque\Desktop\CardTapp.jpg.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>

Comment: @freedomn-m cheek the top comment plz

Comment: Have you tried: `<img src ="C:\Users\ahaque\Desktop\CardTapp.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>` ?

Comment: yeah I tried it but doesn't work....